# HSPCIE Default Value for Float Nodes

Tags: floating, hspice

I have M inputs. I want to connect m of them to Vdd and leave other nodes floating. I know that in real experiments the floating nodes can get any value between 0 and Vdd.
I was wondering how HSPICE will consider those nodes. Will HSPICE automatically connects these nodes to 0/Vdd/...?

Comment: Are these nodes connected to some components inside your circuit?

Comment: @ThePhoton, yes, with wires and resistors.

Comment: Then those components will determine what voltage the node gets when no input source is connected. If you share your circuit (hit Ctrl-M while editing your post) we can give you more helpful information.

Comment: @ThePhoton, yes, you are right. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Hspice will generate an error:

> Node 0 is always ground and floating nodes (a node from which there is
>   no connection to ground through circuit elements) will generate an
>   error.

Source: [MIT Spice Tutorial](http://web.mit.edu/6.012/www/SPICEtutorial.pdf)

The solving matrix can't solve for an equation with a floating node. If you really need to simulate what this would be physically attach a really large resistor on the order of \$ 10^9\$ ohms (or the resistance of air or FR4) to your 'floating node'. Or you could couple them capacitively with a large resistor, physically there are not many situations where you would get a 'floating node' as air and other materials have resistance that need to be accounted for when dealing with very small currents.